# imageView is not fitting correctly to screen

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm quite new writting android apps and i'm facing an issue with my ImageView nto displaying my full picture even is there space on the screen left.
Like it seem my view has some left and right padding event if it is not the case.

**Behaviour :**

Here is my original picture :
[image]

Here you can find the picture that is actually showing up on my screen :
[image]

As you can see my picture is not fully showing up.

**Code**

This is my ImageView code :

```
class DrawableImageView extends ImageView implements FlutterView.OnTouchListener
{
   float downx = 0;
   float downy = 0;
   float upx = 0;
   float upy = 0;
   boolean draw = false;

   Canvas canvas;
   Paint paint;
   Matrix matrix;

   public DrawableImageView(Context context)
   {
       super(context);
       setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

   public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
       super(context, attrs);
       setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

   public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                            int defStyleAttr)
   {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       setOnTouchListener(this);
   }



   public void setNewImage(Bitmap alteredBitmap, Bitmap bmp)
   {
       canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap );
       paint = new Paint();
       paint.setColor(Color.RED);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
       matrix = new Matrix();
       canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

       setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
   }

   public void setDraw(boolean newvalue)  {
       draw = newvalue;
       this.postInvalidate();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
   {
       int action = event.getAction();

      if(draw) {
          switch (action)
          {
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  downx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
                  downy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
                  upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
                  canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                  invalidate();
                  downx = upx;
                  downy = upy;
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
                  upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
                  canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                  invalidate();
                  break;
              case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
          }
      }
       return true;
   }

   final float[] getPointerCoords(MotionEvent e)
   {
       final int index = e.getActionIndex();
       final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
       matrix.postTranslate(getScrollX(), getScrollY());
       matrix.mapPoints(coords);
       return coords;
   }
}
```

Here this is the code of my actual view :

```
public class Markup implements PlatformView, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private MethodChannel methodChannel;
    DrawableImageView choosenImageView;
    Bitmap alteredBitmap;

    private Bitmap bitmap;


    Markup(final Context context, int id, Object args, BinaryMessenger messenger, final PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
        methodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, "plugins.smartapps.flutter_markup/markup_" + id);
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((String) args);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        choosenImageView = new DrawableImageView(context);
        choosenImageView.setMaxWidth(width);
        choosenImageView.setMaxHeight(height);
        choosenImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        choosenImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);


        //scaleBitmap(bitmap);
        alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getConfig());
        choosenImageView.setNewImage(alteredBitmap, bitmap);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return choosenImageView;
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

}
```

I know my post i long but does someone has an idea why this is hapenning ?

Thank you !

Comment: change scale type of your image view to CENTER_CROP or FIT_XY

Comment: @darwin by doing that my imageView is actually takning now the full screen but the picture is still not fully showing up

Comment: Yes, it is the expected behavior, because the resolution(I mean aspect ratio) of the device that you are running application is different from that of your image.

Comment: if you want the image to take full space on the screen then image and screen should have the same aspect ratio.

Comment: @darwin right  but if you see in the original picture the is a wommen on the right side of the picture.
Then if you see the screenshot of the running app the wommen is not showing up anymore even is there is space to render it

Comment: try setting choosenImageView.width and choosenImageView.height instead of maxWidth and maxHeight

Comment: I already tried and it changed nothing

Comment: can u try setting background color instead of bitmap as image view background(for testing).

Comment: while setting the background color, all my screen is filled as intended

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY" or  android:scaleType="centerCrop" //add this property 
/>
```

Comment: Your solution is great for removing the white borders, but it do not change the fact that my full picture is not displayed

Comment: have you added adjustViewBounds="true"?